# django-haystack and external indexing

Tags: python, search, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm trying to understand what's the right way to:

1. feed documents for indexing directly to search backend (just in case I use elasticsearch)
2. then use resulting index from haystack to integrate with a webapp

I noticed that all query requests to elasticsearch backend from haystack go with doc_type='modelresult'. Module haystack/backends/elasticsearch_backend.py is full of hardcoded 'modelresult' entries. I wonder is there a reason for that?

```
[2013-05-31 15:51:50,322][TRACE][index.search.slowlog.query] [Captain Fate] [poces][0] took[207micros], took_millis[0], types[modelresult], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[5], source[{"query":{"filtered":{"filter":{"fquery":{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"django_ct:(snote.note)"}},"_cache":true}},"query":{"query_string":{"query":"(content_auto:(title) AND content_auto:(t1) AND content_auto:(1))","default_operator":"AND","default_field":"text","auto_generate_phrase_queries":true,"analyze_wildcard":true}}}},"from":0}], extra_source[],
```

Should I submit all documents to the search backend with '**modelresult**' doctype to allow haystack to use index?

Is the idea to separate submitting and querying processes bad?

Thanks.